# Alternative to default package with Java 9 and higher

Tags: java, javapackager

I have an application which calls a third party dll.   The dll is written so that the calls to it include the fully qualified name of the class doing the calling.   This module has worked for a number of years using versions of Java earlier than Java 9.   But because of Oracles new restrictions on putting classes in the default package, it no longer works with more recent versions of Java.

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. Can't you just change your Java code to have `package` statements?  What you are saying is that you need to pass it a fully qualified classname to the DLL.  So give it the fully qualified name of a class with a package declaration.

Comment: The bottom line is that because of the way the dll is implemented, we need to add a class that was previously in the default package.   If we move the class to a normal named package, the dll won't work.   So, how can I incorporate the class from the default package into a Java 9 application, without putting into a named package.

Comment: Without an explicit example, it's difficult to determine how to fix this, which probably involves the use of the option `--add-opens` for the jre.